# Bash Script using set and arguments - Trouble echoing 10th argument

Tags: linux, bash, set

Im writing a script where I am trying to use "set" to parse specific argument out of the "last" command. Whenever I echo the tenth argument it spring "$arg1"0"".

For example
Tenth arg is Tuesday
First arg is Yesterday

when echo-ing $10 it gives me Yesterday0

```
${20}
set $(last | head -n 1)

echo
echo $*
echo "Name: $1"
echo "Date: $4 $5 $6"
echo "Time: $7"
echo "Status: $8 $9 $10"
echo
```

I expect the tenth arg to echo "Tuesday"

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo ${10}`. Curly braces are needed for multi-digit variables.